# Why do I get DB error after migrating from codeigniter 2.6 to codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Why do I get DB error after migrating from CodeIgniter 2.6 to CodeIgniter 3?

It adds ",0" after table name.

Ex- SELECT `id`, `title`, `title_url` FROM `tablename`, 0 WHERE `isEnabled` = 'Y' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Showing the code would be a step in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

```
public function functionName()
{
    $this->db->select('id, title, title_url');
    $this->db->from('tablename');
    $this->db->where('isEnabled','Y');
    $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
    $this->db->limit(1); 
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $query;
}
```

Try this once.